# error C2976: 'std::tr1::array' : too few template arguments in MS C++ express 2010

Tags: c++, c++-cli

I'm working on a Windows forms project in C++ Express 2010. Made some changes to the the Form.h and now get an error when compiling the program. Note the compiler suggests the error is in the main program - `open gl test 2` - that `#includes` the form. All compiled fine for days as I developed the code, then changed something last night and now I get the error.

The main program in open gl test 2 is identical to that of any other forms based project I have created - I've compared to check [except for the obvious changes of namespace etc cause its a different project]

```
// open gl test 2.cpp : main project file.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Form1.h"

using namespace opengltest2;

[STAThreadAttribute]
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    // Enabling Windows XP visual effects before any controls are created
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false); 

    // Create the main window and run it
    Application::Run(gcnew Form1());
    return 0;
}
```

The error is:

```
1>open gl test 2.cpp(9): error C2976: 'std::tr1::array' : too few template arguments
1>          D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\array(18) : see declaration of 'std::tr1::array'
1>open gl test 2.cpp(9): error C3699: '^' : cannot use this indirection on type 'std::tr1::array'
1>          compiler replacing '^' with '*' to continue parsing
```

line that compiler is complaining about is

```
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
```

So the fault cant be in where the compiler claims it is - and I can not find a fault in the code in the included files - they compile correctly. I assume the error MUST be in form.h cause that's what I modified that causes this error, but I can not see it. And I'm pretty sure I did not change some project settings.

I ain't including the code for form1.h cause it's toooooo long. Guess what I'm looking for is peoples experience of searching for the error. What strategies can I use to resolve this?  If I had hair to pull out I would be surrounded by it. Please help me save my non-existant hair.

Comment: Wouldn't it be a good idea to include a line of code that causes this error?

Comment: So, why don't you show us line 9 in `test 2.cpp`?

Comment: code added as requested - line that causes error is **int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)** but the file is, with the exception of changes to things such as namespace, the same as any other main project file

Comment: `std::array<T,N>` declares an array of **fixed size**, you need to specify the size as 2nd template parameter.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but the format of the line is exactly the same as in other projects - its an IDE generated line of code

Comment: Could it be you have included `std::array` somewhere in your code and placed a `using namespace std;` statement?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It looks like the compiler is getting confused between the managed array type and the array type in the std library. This is probably because somewhere you're doing `using namespace std` - you should ideally explicitly reference the correct namespace (std::array or cli::array), or remove the include of `<array>` if it's not needed.

Note that the constant size std::array isn't suitable for use with command-line arguments - you'd need to use a variable size container like cli::array anyway.

Comment: Forest and The Tree - spot on answer, else where Ihad added using namespace std which in fact turned out to be un-needed for the code in all of teh prpoject

Comment: Any C++ standard-library header may include any other. So *just* removing the include for `<array>` is a non-solution, even if it might seem to work.

Comment: I recently upgraded a C++/CLI project from a Visual Studio 2010 solution to a Visual Studio 2015 solution.  The compiler was complaining about a similar line of code, array<String^>^ args = Environment::GetCommandLineArgs(); The compiler was definitely confused from several "using namespace std;" lines of code decorated throughout.  I commented all those lines and replaced all calls to functions in the std namespace with fully qualified names, ie. std::ifstream, and voila, all errors were gone.